# Ubuntu and Windows dual boot with Lenovo y50-70

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo y50-70.

I did the partitioning part OK I think, and the Ubuntu works OK, but when I try to choose Windows, I get this error: "The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors."

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."
    
If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD  

  Status: 0xc000000c  

  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

I've tried to reinstall Windows, and then I tried to format the whole computer and restore it to factory's settings, but whenever I get to GRUB Ubuntu keeps popping up and when I try to choose Windows I get the same error.

Apparently grub can't find Windows even though it is there. I can reach it manually when opening the boot menu as suggested here.

Comment: at present your system running on ubuntu or both?

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

The windows bootloader is very destructive and messes up all other bootloaders installed on the system. As a result, you should first install windows with the capacity you would like it to have, and then follow this guide: https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/. Essentially, you should install ubuntu alongside windows 10, with Windows 10 installed first.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to @DevSingh's answer, a possible (but cowardly) choice is to keep separate bootloaders for Windows and Ubuntu, and then to select which system to launch from the BIOS boot menu. Just adds a few seconds on each startup.

Comment: this is what i did in the mean while... but when i have a bit of time i'm gonna try and fix it properly.. thanks